# unable to draw graphs using Vis.js in tornado

Tags: javascript, tornado, vis.js

Hi all iam trying to draw a graph using vis.js in tornado framework but i am unable to achieve that how to direct the file i am right now getting only Helloworld in the url but not the graph 
thanks in advance

```
enter code here Tornado
 import tornado.httpserver
 import tornado.ioloop
 import tornado.options
 import tornado.web
 import os


 from tornado.options import define, options

 define("port", default=8888, help="run on the given port", type=int)
 settings = {
"static_path": os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
"template_path":os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
 }


 class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("graph.html")




 def main():
     tornado.options.parse_command_line()
     application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
    (r"/", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler,
 dict(path=settings['static_path'])),

],**settings)
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

here is the HTML

```
enter code here
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
 <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
 <title>Graph2d | Basic Example</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="{{ static_url("vis.js") }}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ static_url("vis.css") }}"
<script src="../static/vis.js"></script>
<link href="../static/vis.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script>(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');ga('create', 'UA-61231638-1', 'auto');ga('send', 'pageview');</script></head>
<body>
<h1>helloworld</h1>
<div id="visualization"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var container = document.getElementById('visualization');
var items = [
{x: '2014-06-11', y: 10},
{x: '2014-06-12', y: 25},
{x: '2014-06-13', y: 30},
{x: '2014-06-14', y: 10},
{x: '2014-06-15', y: 15},
{x: '2014-06-16', y: 30}
  ];

var dataset = new vis.DataSet(items);
var options = {
start: '2014-06-10',
end: '2014-06-18'
  };
var graph2d = new vis.Graph2d(container, dataset, options);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors do you have? Give some more info, because again your code works as you would expect (tested with vis 4.11.0).  There are some things to fix, even with them everything works, `<link>` in the HTML is incorrectly terminated, and that you have the same resources with `static_url`  (working) and without... everything tornado/rendering is working.

Comment: I am getting 404 vis not found in the terminal , and in the html page I am not getting any error however graph is not being displayed /  deployed @kwarunek

Comment: I jus downloaded vis.js I don't know which version it is can u please tell me what u have done and why it is not working in my environment??

Comment: If possible can u please show ur program :)

Comment: I've added answer - step by step.

Comment: thanks alot brother @kwarunek it worked now can i know why it didnt work previously :|

Comment: if you there were 404, the problem was in dir struct (app.py static templates at same level) or file does not exists. If not 404, might be wrong js - version of vis

Comment: may be now its working good thanks brother :) feels like i got a good tutor for tornado in stackoverflow :P :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested and everything seems to be ok. Make sure that you have static dir. How I've tested

```
~$ virtualenv test
~$ source test/bin/activate  # activate virtualenv
~$ pip install tornado
~$ mkdir static
~$ mkdir templates
~$ wget https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.11.0/vis.min.css -O static/vis.css
~$ wget https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.11.0/vis.min.js -O static/vis.js
~$ # copy your HTML into templates/graph.html
~$ # copy your py into app.py
~$ python app.py
[I 160106 20:46:51 web:1946] 200 GET / (127.0.0.1) 7.46ms
[I 160106 20:46:51 web:1946] 200 GET /static/vis.js?v=1a407e3a47f81c53518823bd11369678 (127.0.0.1) 10.71ms
[I 160106 20:46:51 web:1946] 200 GET /static/vis.css?v=4e678a04d8440cf16f35838950d9d673 (127.0.0.1) 1.67ms
```

[image]